# Scaling out scenario with multiple web server and shared files

Tags: linux, nfs, distributed-system

I need some recommendation or a better suggestion. I have been building a platform and start thinking about what kind of server architecture I need to have. I am not an expert in the server architecture, but when I launch, I need at least a stable production environment until we find a system architect.

I will have about 500GB (or even more) product images and some PDF files as we have more clients later.

I would like to have a minimal set of files (HTML and javascript files) on web servers(2 or 3 in the beginning) and a shared directory where all the product images will reside. I will have some standalone backend java process which will download images and store it into the shared directory, so when a request goes to any web server, a client should be able to see images and pdf files.

I will have Spring MVC in the backend and session will be handled by Redis cluster, so I don't worry about this distributed session handling.

Basically, I need a solution to centralize all the static files(images and PDF files) which will grow exponentially as time goes by and those files are accessible all the time from the web servers.

I have read NFS which can be accessible from web servers.

I am wondering if this NFS is a good solution for this usecase. I am sure this usecase might be a common issue.

Is there a better option instead of NFS?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Many variables will influence the options you could use.  But one of the main criteria is budget.

On the cheap:
1) you have 2 or 3 servers.  So purchase one large disk per system to store your static files, and use rsync to ensure they are all the same. 
 Large disks are cheap, you could even get SSD!  This can grow for a while.
2) same with disks and use something a bit more evolved to ensure sync.  gluster or the inotify mechanisms would do.  There are many more software you could use.
3) NFS is *ok*.  But it does not work very well with high hit web servers.  So your file is there, and available, but if you are hit a lot, you will have performance and/or network issues.  We had that once and we cut the NFS, it was slowing down the site.
4) the NFS shortcomings can be minimized by using caching on the web servers for frequent images.

More expensive:
5) NAS.  There is some dedicated NAS software you could setup with a dedicated file server system.
6) NAS, dedicated hardware, super fast, expensive.  Can grow but $$$.
7) Distributed static files services.  Ex. Akamai.  They store the files and distribute them for you to your clients.  So *their* infrastructure gets the hits.  But it comes at a cost.  The setup is not super complicated, if you can afford it.  You pay by volume.  FYI this is not an endorsement, we used it at my last company, there are probably other vendors that do something similar.

This is a large subject, I hope I got you started with some ideas.